# wamp server vs mysql server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

What is the difference between wamp server and mysqlserver?

and can I construct databases on phpmyadmin using any of these servers?

Comment: after you install WAMP (which is great BTW) use toad instead of that gawd awful phpmyadmin http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between wamp server and mysqlserver ?

They are entirely different products. WAMP server is a bundle of different programs that are used together: Apache (A Web server), mySQL (A database server), and PHP (A programming language).

You can either install WAMP server, or mySQL server alone. The former is easier if your end goal is to use phpMyAdmin.

There are other graphical clients to mySQL though, for example [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) which is *great*.

Answer (score 1):

WAMP is short for Windows Apache MySQL PHP. Basically, when you install WAMP, you have a MySQL server inside and you can do anything you want with it (so also construct databases with phpMyAdmin, yes).